# Reading russian text from property file replaces russian characters with question mark

Tags: java, spring-boot

PROBLEM:

So I have a property file, which contains list of strings and their translations in russian. Format: string.greetings = Привет

Now I want to read this string from code by calling a method where I give string.greetings as input parameter. The translation is readen (which means property file is accessed) but it always prints ??????? marks. But I do not want it to be ????? marks. I want to store Привет inside my string variable and use it for further operations.

---

WHAT I TESTED:

So first of all, my application (Spring Boot application) has a default encoding set to UTF-8. So I tried to use System.out.println() function to see the result. It printed ?????? marks. At first I thought it is just a console problem (I use Intellij IDEA). So I enabled Russian keyboard on my Windows 10 and then I also enabled from File | Settings UTF-8 mode. But it still printed ?????? marks. However when I made just a simple Console application ( which is started with public static void main method ) where I stored Привет in a simple string (not in property file) then it printed just fine. So it seems that there is nothing wrong on console but on encoding itself.

---

CODE:

Property file content:

```java
# Russian labels
string.greetings = Привет
string.back=назад
string.authorize=Авторизоваться
string.logout=Выйти
string.repeat=Повторение
```

Java:

```java
String russianLabel = getMessage("string.greetings");
byte bytes[] = russianLabel .getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
String result= new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

But it still does not seem to work. It still stores ?????? into string. I am out of ideas.

Comment: The first line looks correct; why are you trying to convert it to ISO-8859-1 and then UTF-8? What is the value of `russianLabel`? Also, do you have those spaces for `string.greetings` in your property file? If so, remove them.

Comment: Actually I am bit confused about this encoding / decoding stuff. I read that property files have ISO 8859-1 unicode. So I thought that I need it. (And I do not have any spaces there and value of russianLabel is ???????)